# Haskell - passing a function as a argument compilation error

Tags: haskell

I have a very simple function called 'fold' that takes a function f and executes it. Given a function 'add' and two numbers it calls add with those two numbers and displays the results. However I cannot compile it due to a compilation error below. What is the error specifically stating and what can I do to solve it?

```
  module Main where

    add x y = x + y

  --fold :: ((a,b)->c) -> a->b->c

    fold f n x = f n x


    main :: IO ()
    main = do 
        fold add 2 3
```

[image]

Comment: You stated that `main` should return a `IO ()`. What does `fold add 2 3` return? How can you turn the returned value to a `IO ()`?

Comment: If I change IO() to Integer it gives "Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘Integer’"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `main` (correctly) as having type `IO ()`, but `fold` doesn't return that. The error message is a little more complicated because in *theory*, `add` (and thus `fold`) could return a value of type `IO ()`, since `add` can return any type with a `Num` instance. `IO ()`, however, is *not* an instance of `Num`. The solution is to return an IO action created from the return value of `fold`. One way to do that is to use the `print` function (which takes any value with a `Show` instance and converts it to a `String` before outputing it).

```
main = print $ fold add 2 3
```